# How to Segue from different Collection View Cells to different View Controllers

Tags: swift, collections, view, segue, viewcontroller

Beginner here. I am developing a simple fixtures app. I have set up a collection view, I am trying to make it so when I click on a cell in the collection view it takes me to the corresponding view controller. Each cell should segue to a different view controller. Here is the code I have tried so far:

```
import UIKit

class FixturesViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource,       UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


let fixturesName = ["EUMHC 1's XI", "EUMHC 2's XI", "EUMHC 3's XI", "EUMHC 4's XI", "EUMHC 5's XI", "EUMHC 6's XI", "EUMHC 7's XI"]

let fixturesLeague = ["Competing in Men's Premiership & Premier North (BUCS)", "Competing in Men's Regional Division 1 & Scottish 1 (BUCS)", "Competing in Men's Regional Division 2 & Scottish 2 (BUCS)", "Competing in Men's East District Division 1 & Scottish 3 (BUCS)", "Competing in Men's East District Division 2 & Scottish 3 (BUCS)", "Competing in Men's East District Division 2 & Scottish 4 (BUCS)", "Competing in Men's East District Division 4"]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return fixturesName.count
   }



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath) as! FixturesCollectionViewCell

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    }

    cell.fixturesName.text = fixturesName[indexPath.row]
    cell.fixturesLeague.text = fixturesLeague[indexPath.row]


    cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1.0)
    cell.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = false
    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0

    return cell


}

private func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

switch (indexPath.row)   {
    case 0:
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "fixtures1", sender: self)
    case 1:
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "fixtures2", sender: self)
  default:
     break
   }
}
}
```

I've tried to use a switch statement at the bottom (saw this method elsewhere) to perform segues with identifiers depending on the index of the cell.

Is this the right way to approach it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have many segues , then it's better to build this way

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "fixtures\(indexPath.item + 1)", sender: self)
```

where segues start with `fixtures1` to `fixturesN`

Comment: thanks so much for this! Where should I imbed that in my code so that it works properly. Sorry for the beginner question

Comment: inside `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`

Comment: ok that's what I've done but cells still aren't clickable is there something I'm missing to make them so? If its important I defined the segues from the storyboard and gave them identifiers fixtures1 to fixturesn there

Comment: Thanks so much for this just had to change a few parts of my original code to get it to work absolutely ecstatic now been stuck on this for ages. Cheers again!